# Right-align a bootstrap nav-item not dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar and I am trying to put the `Login/Register` on the right of the navbar. I have looked at other answers on this website, and they all are for dropdowns or they don't work for me.
Here is the Navbar code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
  <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center text-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        AMENITIES
                    </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NEIGHBOURHOOD SOCIAL DECK</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">POOLS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        RESOURCES
                    </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ACCEPTED PAINT COLORS</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PROCESS FOR CHANGE</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MANAGEMENT COMPANY CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BOARD MEMBERS</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CLOSING INFORMATION</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MEETING MINUTES</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CALENDAR</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried surrounding the Login/Register Nav item with this: `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`, but it did not work. I am using Bootstrap 5.3.

here is the full code. I have just updated my Navbar so that a `ul` with a class containing `ml-auto`, but it still does not work. Maybe it has something to do with the way I am including bootstrap?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block title %}

        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c6f651f0e2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 50px; ">Welcome to Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1004130719643461/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2xl"></i></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- TODO: PUT THE NAVBAR HERE -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center text-left">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">HOME</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        AMENITIES
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NEIGHBOURHOOD SOCIAL DECK</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">POOLS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        RESOURCES
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ACCEPTED PAINT COLORS</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PROCESS FOR CHANGE</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MANAGEMENT COMPANY CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BOARD MEMBERS</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CLOSING INFORMATION</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MEETING MINUTES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CALENDAR</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a> 
                </li>
                <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
                </li> -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE -->
    {% block content %}
    
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
    <style>
        h1{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .nav-link {
            font-size: 25px !important;
            margin-right: 15px !important;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }

    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: On the <li> tag that you need moving to the left, put the class "ml-auto" on that or "pull-right".

Comment: @Tehcheatah That does nothing in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `login` to the different `ul` list. And add `display: flex` to the container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block title %}

        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c6f651f0e2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 50px; ">Welcome to Crabapple Lake Parc</h1>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1004130719643461/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2xl"></i></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- TODO: PUT THE NAVBAR HERE -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center text-left">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">HOME</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        AMENITIES
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">NEIGHBOURHOOD SOCIAL DECK</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">POOLS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        RESOURCES
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ACCEPTED PAINT COLORS</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PROCESS FOR CHANGE</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MANAGEMENT COMPANY CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BOARD MEMBERS</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CLOSING INFORMATION</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MEETING MINUTES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CALENDAR</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a> 
                </li>
                <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
                </li> -->
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- OTHER CONTENT HERE -->
    {% block content %}
    
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
    <style>
        h1{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .nav-link {
            font-size: 25px !important;
            margin-right: 15px !important;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }

    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I just want login/register on the right

Comment: If you push "run code snippet" button inside my answer, you should see list on the left, and `Login/Register` on the right. I thought this is what you wanted to achieve.
if it is not, please explain in more details what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If I paste this in my code, it does not work. What happens is everything but the login/register goes to the left, not right, and the login/register disappears

Comment: If it works here in a snippet and doesn't work when you paste it to your code, that means that something in your code overrides the correct behaviour.

Comment: Take a look at the edit I just made

Comment: You have included `ul` with the "login\register" inside the main `ul`.
But they should be on the same level. 
Please check my edited answer